# How to read email attachment from a VIEW Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, email-attachments

I am trying to read an email attachment in my Android app. The Intent filter is working: when I tap on the attachment in the GMail app, my app is listed as one of the candidates for opening the attachment, and when I select it, the appropriate Activity's onCreate() method is called. However, when I then try to read the data from the Intent, I get a FileNotFoundException.

The onCreate() method in my attachment handling Activity looks like this (edited for brevity):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    System.err.println("FileImportActivity action = " + action);
    Uri uri = intent.getData();
    System.err.println("FileImportActivity uri = " + uri);
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        // Read the attachment from the InputStream and process it
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // [...]
    }
    finish();
}
```

I'm getting this output:

```
FileImportActivity action = android.intent.action.VIEW
FileImportActivity uri = content://com.android.email.attachmentprovider/1/17/RAW
java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:144)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:698)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1458)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1295)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:1015)
        at com.thomasokken.free42.FileImportActivity.onCreate(FileImportActivity.java:40)
```

The Intent and the Uri look OK, and the getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri) call is how the examples I've seen all say to open the attachment. The FileNotFoundException includes no detail about what file it's failing to open. I don't see anything in the system log to indicate what the problem might be, either; the output I'm showing here is all from print statements in my code. What am I missing?